# Session hijacking and IP monitor

Tags: session, cookies, browser

I'm experminenting by copying and pasting cookies from one browser to the other. I came to the conclusion that it's very easy for a attacker to log in to your account when he has your cookies.

This is a part of a highly secured website:

> If a withdrawal is requested from a new IP address you will receive an
> email asking you to check and verify the withdrawal. The 'untrusting'
> period for IP changes is 24 hours. If the withdrawal is made more than
> 24 hours after the IP address change, this extra email check is not
> triggered.

Question: If a attacker hijacks my session, can the website see that there are 2 sessions active with 2 different IP adresses? Or do they just see the new IP address when you manually log in using your credentials?

Answer (score 0):

It's sure that the website can see the sessions active with different IP. If trying to bind IP with cookies because of security, it's not a wise choice. [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/107811) shows why. Hope it can help you.

Great day.